# $P ⇒ (Q ∨ S)$ , how can I prove $Q$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm asking this in the context of a logical programming language similar to Prolog.

Say I have the rule $P ⇒ (Q ∨ S)$ . How would I go about proving the truth value of $Q$, assuming I know the values of $S$ and $P$, and possibly other information.

I've thought about it and found that I could prove that $Q$ is True for $(P ∧ ¬S)$ , in other words $Q$ must be True if $P$ is True and $S$ is False. However I can't seem to figure out what to do if $S$ is True.

Any help is appreciated !

edit : thanks @ervx for pointing out $P ⇒ Q ∨ S$ vs $P ⇒ (Q ∨ S)$

Comment: I assume you want $P\implies (Q\vee S)$ above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P\implies (Q\vee S)$ is equivalent, as you pointed out, to $(\neg P\vee S)\vee Q$. Thus, to show that $Q$ is true, given only this information, you must show that $(\neg P\vee S)$ is false; i.e., that $P$ is true and $S$ is false. Without any more information, there is not way to conclude for sure that $Q$ is true. If $P$ and $S$ are true, then $Q$ could indeed be false and the statement $P\implies (Q\vee S)$ would still be true.

Answer (score 1):

A more compact way of seeing this is simply that $\bot \lor S \iff S$. So $P \Rightarrow S$ is equivalent to $P \Rightarrow (\bot \lor S)$ which is to say $Q$ need not be true if $P \Rightarrow S$ holds (though, of course, $Q$ still could be true).